# Using pylsp within vscode

Tags: vscode-extensions

There are tutorials teaching how to apply [vscode extension](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/get-started/extension-anatomy#extension-entry-file) in general and how to build [language client/server](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/language-server-extension-guide) using Node SDK. Based on those tutorials, I want to understand how to integrate a language server e.g. [pylsp](https://github.com/python-lsp/python-lsp-server) in vscode. I created the "HelloWorld" extension and try to add the LSP client code from the other tutorial to `src/extension.ts` with modifications below. Not sure if I'm on the right track. After pressing F5 and `shift+ctrl+P` to run the HelloWorld command, how can I examine if the client-server communication is working?

```
export function activate(context: vscode.ExtensionContext) {
    let serverOptions: ServerOptions = {
        command: 'python3',
        args: ['-m', 'pylsp']
      };
      let clientOptions: LanguageClientOptions = {
        documentSelector: [{ scheme: 'file', language: 'python' }],
        synchronize: {
          fileEvents: vscode.workspace.createFileSystemWatcher('**/*.py')
        }
      };
      client = new LanguageClient(
        'languageServerExample',
        'Language Server Example',
        serverOptions,
        clientOptions
      );
    
      client.start();
      let disposable = vscode.commands.registerCommand('lspclient.helloWorld', () => {
      vscode.window.showInformationMessage('Hello World from LSPClient!');
    });

    context.subscriptions.push(disposable);
}
```